# Call async function inside non-async function

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Before I use

```
protected async void OnResume() {
  await DoWorkAsync(); // assume exception is appropriately handled
  await DoOtherWorkAsync(); 
}
```

But now I saw other developers use

```
protected void OnResume() {
  SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(async (status) => {
  await DoWorkAsync(); 
  await DoOtherWorkAsync();}, null);
}
```

Is the second one correct and preferred when calling async methods inside non-async methods? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: 
  If you use the 2nd snippet, you must call `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post()` on UI Thread, or you will get `NullReferenceException`, cause `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null on non-UI Thread. `_handler.Post(async() => {// do UI changes});` can be called on non-UI Thread to do any UI changes, as long as `_handler` is instantiated on UI Thread.

Comment: If You can make your method async - do it as it's a common patern nowadays. If it could possibly cause some troubles -  You can use second solution as it is correct nothing bad about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't use `SynchronizationContext`. You're already on the UI thread, so the second option really makes no sense.

Note that normally `async void` should be avoided. In this case, I'd say it's acceptable because you're actually treating `OnResume` *as though it were* an event handler:

```
protected async void OnResume()
{
  await DoWorkAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, the second one throws null reference exception for SynchronizationContext.Current if SynchronizationContext.Current.Post is called from non-UIThread.

Comment: @macio.Jun: Probably because `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`.

Comment: Yeah, `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null. I really don't know why `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null when it's called on non-UIThread. MSDN says property `Current` **Gets the synchronization context for the current thread**.

Comment: @macio.Jun: It's because by default threads do not have a synchronization context. UI frameworks to add one to their UI threads because they need one. But in general, random thread pool threads are not going to have one.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, UI frameworks added context to UI Thread by default and all other threads do not have context added by default. Is that correct?

Comment: @macio.Jun: Yes. There are other contexts, too, but that's a good summary for UI applications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94025/discussion-between-macio-jun-and-stephen-cleary).

Answer (score 2):

Both examples are performing unnecessary work.  The best implementation of the method would be:

```
protected void OnResume() 
{
    DoWorkAsync();
}
```

In the first case you're forcing a continuation to run in the current context but that continuation has nothing to actually do; it's just pointlessly adding a post to the synchronization context.

The second snippet is adding *two* pointless posts two the current synchronization context, one explicitly, and one implicitly.

Both methods also have `async` methods that are adding state machines, even though you don't actually leverage any of that functionality, so that overhead is all entirely wasted.

Comment: The first example and your code differ in how exceptions from `DoWorkAsync` are treated.

Comment: @StephenCleary The comment in the code indicates that `DoWorkAsync` never throws; it handles all of its own exceptions internally.

Comment: Hi @Servy, sorry for the misleading. Actually I do need make sure DoOtherWorkAsync() is called after DoWorkAsync() is finished.

Comment: @macio.Jun Then making the method `async` isn't pointless.  Posting to the synchronization context you're already in to invoke the same `async` method still would be.

Comment: Thanks @Servy. The second snippet does unnecessarily force DoWorkAsync to be called on UI Thread although OnResume is already on the UI Thread. But without SynchronizationContext.Current.Post then I have to use the first snippet to call async methods.